# How to decode/unescape HTML in Dynamics AX

Tags: html, xml-serialization, decode, dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics

I have some HTML encoded within an XML request I get through an AIF web service.

The text I'm getting is of course escaped - I get &lt;br&gt; instead of <br> .

Is there a proper way to decode it? I don't want to write something for the basic stuff, then deal with bug reports for the next decade, because I forgot an accented character I never knew existed...

The lame part is, that when I feed special HTML/XML characters to XMLTextWriter, it will properly encode them, but if I feed that same XML to XMLTextReader, it will not decode them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static void HtmlDecode(Args _args)
{
    str input   = '&lt;br&gt;';
    str output  = System.Web.HttpUtility::HtmlDecode(input);
    ;

    info(output);
}
```

Result: `<br>`

Comment: Thanks. I've been searching for this for a while and no luck. In fact, this question is now the top google hit for 'ax html decode'...